# Azure Web Application Crashing 10 to 30 minutes + App Pool Recycles

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I am seeing these errors in "Application Crashes"

88 crashes due to (0xC0000005 - Native Access Violation), 4 crashes due to (0xE0434352 - CLR Exception)

App Service is running on S3 app service plan.  Memory and CPU don't seem to be an issue.

Doesn't seem to be consistent, seems to crash every 20 to 30 minutes but can sometimes be quicker.  Always On is enabled.

Comment: Native Access Violation - usually represents an issue with underlying drivers or 3rd party libraries.  Add additional logging to identify what components are causing the issues.

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused the Native Access Violation? I am seeing these, too, though only once a month or so...

Comment: Yes was an out of date DLL. Sorry can't remember exact details.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't alot to go on here but would suggest the following to try and narrow down...

- Make sure any 3rd party libs you're using are supported on the version of .NET in the app service.
- Enable [diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) to get additional details on the fail to see if the problem area can be narrowed down
- Enable app insights to help narrow down
- If the above doesn't help, you could try and recreate the issue locally so you can debug as described [here](http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2009/07/finding-clr-exceptions-with-visual.html)